# Imageview should be on top of other layout

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to put the trash over the bottom right corner of the FrameLayout/ConstraintLayout. So that this is covered by the wastebasket. Here is my code so far

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/addNewImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/newStoreImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></ImageView>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteImage"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_delete_24"
        android:background="@drawable/delete_icon"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"></ImageView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]